# Is it possible to use a php form/button to insert a new table into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I just wondered if this is possible as I have been trying to find out if you can for some time but I must be searching google with the wrong vocabulary or something!

For reference I am trying to make it so people can go on my site and click a button/simple form submit and a new table is created in my database. This will then show a link to the individual table's webpage (e.g. www.mysite.com/pageid=1234)

Thanks guys!

Can someone just push me in the right direction?
Please don't be harsh and downgrade my first question I have nowhere else to turn to!

James

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this:

"This will then show a link to the individual table's webpage"

Comment: Creating tables on the fly is usually a bad idea. Why does it need to be a table?

Comment: Just Google [php create table](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+create+table). First link has code. But do you mind me asking, why in the world do you need to do this?

Comment: yes it's possible you may use ajax for that if you like.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a table, and not just a row? Can you explain why you think you need a new table for every user? BTW if you are using MySQL, see this page for the `CREATE TABLE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: It could be a row but I'm not sure how it works with a row. I want people to create a new row which is then given its own id which then allows it to have its own webpage link. This link will then be shown and can be copied onto other sites where others can click the link copied and enter information to the page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a row then. What database system are you using?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Good plan? No. I think it would make more sense if you had one table for all your users and then when somebody fills in the form you create a new _row_ in the table.

Comment: Just assuming your comment is not a troll: How is ajax going to help? PHP, MySQL and HTML are already enough to study on for the next weeks...

Comment: h right, ok say a user comes to my site and fills out a form with use a name input. So the row in the database will use be id and name. example: 1 John. So now that row has its own webpage link like www.mysite.com/idpage=1 people can go onto the link and comment on that row. But where do i store the row's comments?

Comment: @user1126896 in a different table called `comments` foreign key `user_id` primary key `comment_id`

Answer (score 1):

Yep... you'd just run it as you'd run any other query:

```
$add_table = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `example` ( `id` INT, `data` VARCHAR(100));",[CONNECTION IDENTIFIER]);
```

Just make sure that your connection identifier is logging into the mysql database with a user that has permissions to add tables.

Comment: This is  correct, but creating tables dynamically is still an awful, awful thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a new *table*? Generally, tables are the structures you create to run your site. You'd create a photos table, and users would upload photos as rows in that table. Or you'd create a blog_posts table, and users would add posts as rows to that table.

I suggest you look at a tutorial for creating basic web applications with PHP/MySQL. [Creating blogs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/) is usually a good place to start—you'll get your feet wet, and it should point you in the right direction.

More resources:

1. http://www.blazonry.com/scripting/linksdb/
2. http://www.hosting.vt.edu/tutorials/phpmysql/

#### Edits

You'll want to create two tables: `pages` and `comments`.

```
pages
*------*------*-------------*
|  id  | name | intro text? |
*------*------*-------------*

comment
*------*------*--------------*---------*
|  id  | name | comment text | page_id |
*------*------*--------------*---------*
```

Then, on **index.php:**

```
<?php
$page_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page_id']);
myql_query("SELECT * from `pages` WHERE `id` = $page_id");

//code to display page creator's name + intro text

myql_query("SELECT * from `comments` WHERE `page_id` = $page_id");
//code to display commenter's name + comment text
?>
```

You can associate comments in the `comments` table with a certain page by also storing the `page_id` of the comment. Does that make sense? Again, I highly recommend you start by following the blog tutorial. I know you don't want to create a blog, but creating your own web application from scratch will be *much* easier.

Comment: Ah right, ok say a user comes to my site and fills out a form with use a name input. So the row in the database will use be id and name. example: 1 John. So now that row has its own webpage link like www.mysite.com/idpage=1 people can go onto the link and comment on that row. But where do i store the row's comments?

Comment: @user, see my edits! I really, really think you should try creating a blog by following that tutorial first. Relational databases will make much more sense after that.